# Better Readability with epub Books

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-5, ebook-reader, epub

I'm seeking a method to re-format epubs to be more readable on an Android phone (specifically the SGS5).

Epubs are awesome, however there are some issues I've come across with a huge majority of them: they weren't meant to be read on a phone. This leads to, for instance, the contents of a single page being compressed into a single, massive paragraph with annotations at the end of the paragraph. A single one of these paragraphs takes up about 2.5 "pages" in the reader I use. As you can imagine, this makes it difficult to read. I would like a method to ameliorate this issue.

I have seen a few methods for reformatting epubs, but they all require ready access to a PC, which I do not have, or manually editing the config files themselves, which is a more time-consuming endeavor than I care to undertake. So I need a quick method of reformatting epubs for readability on the Galaxy S5. I am also open to suggestions for an epub reader that might fix them for me.

Answer (score 0):

I use "UB reader" on my galaxy s5 and It has alot of customisation with epubs such as, font size, background/text color, index, bookmarks ect. Seems as I can change the font size i find it comfortable at 9pt witch for an average size book is 2 screens to one book page. hope this helps.